# Establishing communication between two exchange 2010 servers on the same domain

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2010, email-server

I just added a second exchange 2010 server to my domain, but internal e-mails sent to mailboxes on on the other server seem to get lost.

Example:
JohnS' mail box is on EX01 and BobT's mail box is on EX02

John sends bob an e-mail (internal), but bob doesn't ever get the e-mail. But, both are receiving e-mails from the outside world just fine and sending to external addresses fine.

Now let's say Susie's mail box is on EX01. Both her and John can send mail to one another but not to or from Bob.

The problem is all internal. EX01 and EX02 are in the same domain but seem to not be sending to one another.

Need some help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have connectors setup properly between the 2 machines?

[Connectors between 2 Exchange servers](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/exchange2010/exchange_2010_smtp_connector.htm)

Comment: I've setup both send and receive connectors and can send messages from EX02 to EX01 now, but not from EX01 to to EX02

Answer (score 0):

I would double check your settings on the connectors. On each server, open the connector, go to Network tab, make sure you have the other server's IP address set to be allowed to connect. Also on Authentication tab enable Exchange Server authentication.

And of course your logs are a wealth of information. I would look in the SMTP logs for errors related to the users in question.

SMTP Logs are here by default:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\TransportRoles\Logs\ProtocolLog\SmtpReceive
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\TransportRoles\Logs\ProtocolLog\SmtpSend

I seem to remember that SMTP logging is not turned on by default. If the above folders are empty or don't exist, enable logging: 
Open Exchange console>Server Configuration>Hub Transport.
Right click your server go to Properties, then Log Settings tab. Enable logging and make sure you set Send & Receive protocol log paths.